# printing array inside echo command

Tags: bash

how to print myArray inside echo command?

```
declare -a myArray=([0]="AAA" [1]="AAC" [2]="AAG" [3]="AAU" [4]="ACA" [5]="ACC" [6]="ACG" [7]="ACU" [8]="AGA" [9]="AGC" [10]="AGG" [11]="AGU" [12]="AUA" [13]="AUC")
```

I know it can be done in this way

```
echo ${myArray[@]}
```

or

```
for i in ${myArray[@]}
do
 echo $i
done
```

how to do it in a single echo command like this, (like in python)

```
echo ${  for i in ${myArray[@]} }  # does not work
```

Comment: But why would you use `echo` then?

Comment: @Niransha: `${...}` is parameter expansion. Inside the curlys, you need the name of a variable, not a command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use command subsitution

```
echo "$(for i in ${myArray[@]}; do echo $i; done)"
```

But I think you really mean to:

```
printf "%s\n" "${myArray[@]}"
```

Answer (score 4):

Consider printf:

```
printf '%s\n' "${myArray[@]}"
```

But don't forget the quotes, or your expansion will be wordsplit when you don't want it to!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this :

```
for i in ${myArray[@]}; do  echo $i; done
```